# What is the Aramaic phrase that is translated "Truly I say to you" or "Amen lego humin" in the gospels?

Tags: new-testament, gospels

I am interested in trying to find out what Jesus would have said in Aramaic. The particular phrase "Truly I say to you" or "Truly truly ..." in John's gospel, sounds to me like it might have been a catchphrase, commonly used by Jesus.

Since disciples used to imitate their masters, striving to copy not just their words but their tone of voice, it seems likely to me that Jesus' disciples may have fastened on to this significant saying of his and quoted it verbatim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In John 6:26 the Syriac Bible (Pshitta) has: ܐܡܝܢ ܐܡܝܢ ܐܡܪ ܐܢܐ ܠܟܘܢ , Eastern Syriac reading : ʼāmēn, ʼāmēn, ʼāmar nā lḵōn. However, ʼāmēn is not Aramaic; it is a Hebrew loan word.

Comment: Can I ask you a few things? ;) — **①** Is there some online version of the Syriac text? **②** What tool do you use to transliterate the Syriac text?

Comment: (1) The whole of the Syriac NT is here: http://www.dukhrana.com/

Comment: (2) The dukhrana site offers a transliteration according to the Western Syriac pronunciation (click where it says "transliteration > Latin"). The Eastern Syriac transcription given above is my own work.